# How to terminate process in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I have just started working with hibernate and When I run a query using HQL netbeans in the bottom right corner informs me its processing results.  Each query adds to the list of processes that are running.  Another way to view which processes are running was from going to the menu and selecting Window->Processes.

Anyways netbeans gives no indication what each process is and it keeps getting hung up at 80% this is on every process.  This happens on queries that fail and ones that return data. I want to terminate the processes. If you right click on the process 3 options come up Show Output, Watch Process, and Cancel Process.  The first and third options are grayed out.  So where would you go to cancel a process if this fails.  Only way I've found to cancel the processes is to exit out of netbeans at which point it alerts me that exiting the IDE will terminate the following processes: and it list them all off.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: I would test this only I do not have access to the code anymore due to being at a different company.  That being said, I think I was looking for something within netbeans specifically that would allow me to kill a process and not so much done through coding.